# I have a '93 Pontiac firebird with a 5.7 i believe I have a coolant block in my engine. How can I fix itblock

Tags: coolant

I have already replaced thermostat, fan motor, and water pump, flushed out radiator

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the problem which has brought you to this conclusion? If it's overheating, how did you bleed the coolant system? (And details will be good here). The Gen II SBC (which is what should be in your vehicle) has a very specific bleeding procedure to it due to the reverse flow cooling.